# Collected by or collected from

Tags: word-usage, meaning, grammar, prepositions, difference

Below mentioned items has been **collected from** Mr.suresh or **collected by** Mr. Suresh
Which is correct word to use in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

If Mr Suresh was the person who collected the items, the sentence should be:

> The below mentioned items have been collected by Mr Suresh.

If Mr Suresh was the person who was originally in possession of the items, the sentence should be:

> The below mentioned items have been collected from Mr Suresh.

Note some other small changes.

- Added the definite article at the beginning of the sentence.
- Changed *has been* (singular) to *have been* (plural).
- Removed the full stop after "Mr" because my usage is English.
  American usage favours including the period as "Mr."

Comment: If this is the best answer, please "accept" it by checking the box.

Comment: @WeatherVane  interesting, I didn't know the English omit the period after title abbreviations.

Comment: @Andrew it is when the abbreviation starts and finishes with the same letters as the original word. Another example is *ry* for *railway*. In other cases the stop indicates the word was truncated, for example *etc.* is *etcetera* truncated.